# How to auto login admin after fresh WordPress installation?

Tags: php, wordpress, single-sign-on

I am building a WordPress auto-installer for cPanel which installs a fresh version of WordPress. Once the installation has completed I provide links to the front-end and to the back-end (wp-admin).

I want it so that when they click the back-end URL it will automatically log them in as the admin user which was created during the installation.

How can I do this simply and securely?

I was wondering if using the following functions during installation could work.

```
wp_set_current_user(1, $this->input->admin_username);
wp_set_auth_cookie(1);
do_action('wp_login', $this->input->admin_username);
```

Then I could pass a cookie or authentication key to the WP Admin URL.

If not, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: after `wp_set_auth_cookie` you just need to do a redirection and the user is logged in.

Comment: @Kaperto only issue with that is I don't want it to automatically redirect them inside cPanel. It could open a new tab and redirect them there but ideally only once they click the link will it open a new tab.